# Only first request mapping resolves Java Spring Boot (circular view path)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to map several request paths in my Spring Boot application. It's a RESTful web service but I wanted to have two views (**main** and **help**) for user interface. I've tried tweaking the names of the return string (ie. from "help.html to "help"), as well as cleaning my project and rebuilding, but I cannot figure why one view resolves and the other view does not and returns a circular path. I've also tried creating a separate **HelpController** and mapping it there. I don't see anything different I am doing between the two.

Here is my **MainController.java**:

```
   @Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/help", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String help(){
        System.out.println("GET called on help page");
        return "help.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String landing(){
        System.out.println("GET called on index page");
        return "landing.html";
    }
}
```

**My App.java:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class App {

//    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(App.class.toString());

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

I put my two html templates in the resources/static directory:

[image: directory view]

But only one of these two paths resolve correctly. **main.html** looks great:
[image]

But **help.html** has a circular reference I cannot resolve or understand:[image]

Here is my **pom.xml** (certain tags omitted for privacy):

```
  <build>

    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>dynamodb-local-oregon</id>
            <name>DynamoDB Local Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.derjust/spring-data-dynamodb -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
          <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
          <version>1.11.125</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
          <version>Gosling-SR1</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
          <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
          <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
          <version>${jackson.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
          <artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>
          <version>${aws.dynamodblocal.version}</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simplest way to solve your issue is to change the mapping from `/help` to something else, or rename the static file `help.html`.

The reason for the circular dependency is because the view name `help.html` will again get mapped to your controller. Spring MVC uses a suffix to determine a mimetype of the response by default, this means that a method mapped to `/help`, will intercept the `/help.html` request as well